# 301 Redirect in the body?

Tags: 301-redirect

This may be a silly question, but if I only have access to edit a website through a CMS, and can't touch the headers, is there a way to redirect the page without prompting the user to click a link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to redirect them with code in the `<body>` of the page. It won't be a 301 redirect, however, as you can only do that with HTTP headers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
</script>
```

Comment: perfect.  I figured it would have to be js.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what is the objective.

If it is a permanent, it is better creating a `.htaccess` file with

`Redirect /what http://some.tld/where`

Comment: They said they only have access to the website through a CMS. That would imply they cannot upload or create a .htaccess file.

Comment: Indeed.  I don't have FTP access to anything so modifying a .htaccess file is out of the question.  The JS redirect works good.  Thank you for your answer, though.